# How to map array of objects, mapping their keys without nested loops?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

How to map an array of objects to another array of objects with multiple key changes? It is given what keys I have to change before the loop starts.

I am doing it using two loops: one for map, and another for key changes.

Example:

```js
var data = [{"result.rows.author_id":1,"result.rows.name":"Ames T","result.rows.orcid":""},{"result.rows.author_id":2,"result.rows.name":"Argasinska J","result.rows.orcid":"0000-0003-2678-2824"}];
var OKeys= ["result.rows.author_id", "result.rows.name", "result.rows.orcid"];
var DKeys= ["id", "name", "orcid"];
var countLength = OKeys.length;

var mappedData = data.map(function(obj) {
  var newObj = {};
  /* How we can remove this loop and still map to new keys */
  for(var i=0;i<countLength;i++) {
      newObj[DKeys[i]] = obj[OKeys[i]];
  }
  return newObj;
});

console.log(mappedData);
```

I want to know is there any way I can remove **countLength** loop and still be able to map to new keys or any other way to optimize this two nested loop in one loop.

Comment: Each array much be iterated over. This is a classic matrix issue. When dealing with a multi-dimensional matrix of values that  correspond in some way, each set must be iterated over to determine how that particular set evolves into a different structure.

Answer (score 1):

If the set of keys to read/write are dynamic, then you'll have to iterate them for each object you want to translate: the number of changes to perform is equal to the number of objects times the number of keys. By consequence you'll have a nested loop.

However, maybe you would like to make the code more *functional programming* style, so that the inner loop is also a kind of mapper that *returns* the new object format:

```js
var data = [{"result.rows.author_id":1,"result.rows.name":"Ames T","result.rows.orcid":""},{"result.rows.author_id":2,"result.rows.name":"Argasinska J","result.rows.orcid":"0000-0003-2678-2824"}];
var OKeys= ["result.rows.author_id", "result.rows.name", "result.rows.orcid"];
var DKeys= ["id", "name", "orcid"];

var mappedData = data.map(obj =>
  Object.fromEntries(OKeys.map((k, i) => [DKeys[i], obj[k]]))
);

console.log(mappedData);
```

Comment: It is good but are we getting some performance improvement ?

Comment: No, that is not expected. As I wrote, the time complexity is already at a minimum. If you have questions specifically about performance, then you should really go to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). But I can already tell you that for performance you should go the other way, and use only standard, old-fashioned `for` loops -- so no `map`.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?
If you're just mapping it to new key names.

```js
var data = [{"result.rows.author_id":1,"result.rows.name":"Ames T","result.rows.orcid":""},{"result.rows.author_id":2,"result.rows.name":"Argasinska J","result.rows.orcid":"0000-0003-2678-2824"}];

const test = data.map((obj) => ({
  id: obj["result.rows.author_id"],
  name: obj["result.rows.name"],
  orcid: obj["result.rows.orcid"]
}))

console.log(test)
```

Comment: I am getting source keys and destination keys at runtime and they are dynamic.. I have to fetch using Okeys and Dkeys..